# How to escape XML code snippet embedded in a HTML page

Tags: html, xml, escaping

We are building a WebUI for a backend that processes XML data. The customer wants to see **XML** in the GUI **together with normal HTML Elements** (like Headers, Labels and Input fields).

Here some pseudoCode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>

        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>

    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Check Out that XML!</h1>

      <div>
        <!-- This does not work. Just to make clear what I want -->
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <note>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <heading>Reminder</heading>
          <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
        </note>
      </div>

      <p>What you see above is XML....</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Basicly what we want to achive is, to create an area (lets say a div) that displays an XML file in the middle of an xhtml website. (Separation in multiple windows is not possible, as we need to show additional data together with the XML file)
The users work with IE11 and are used to/dependent on the XML folding feature that comes with the plain XML in Browser window.

What ways do exist to

- display XML inside an xhtml site
- highlight the XML (idealy make the values inside the XML bolder than the tags)
- allow the user to fold parts of the XML

Ideas I allready followed

- escape the XML + use prettify for highlighting

  - no folding
  - highlighting of values in XML not as nice as in IE

Comment: The Good Old iframe Comes to the rescue Here. And you would have the same issue/ Question in plain HTML

Answer (score 0):

I build a SAXHandler that converted everything into encoded strings. 
Methods I used:

- startCDATA()
- endCDATA()
- characters()
- startElement()
- endElement()

Each of those functions wrote into a List. After parsing I used the content of the List as my result.

I oriented myself on this solution from Lev Muchnik:
http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/DisplayXMLFileWithJavascript.html